# Webpacker creates only the manifest.json file, so assets are missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm building a Rails 5.2 application with the webpacker gem.

I followed the installation instructions so that I have the `app/javascript/packs/application.js` file, and the `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` in my layout.

After having started my unicorn server, the `bin/webpack-dev-server` process and I'm accessing the app, the network tab of the webbrowser shows me that he can't download the the `/packs/application-bdddc5e750615fa56298.js` file from my server due to an End of file error from the webpack server (500 error).

Doing an `ls -al` in the `public/packs` folder show me the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 zedtux zedtux 4096 Apr  4 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 zedtux root   4096 Apr  4 16:35 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 zedtux zedtux  352 Apr  4 16:35 manifest.json
```

And the `manifest.json` contains :

```
{
  "application.js": "/packs/application-bdddc5e750615fa56298.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/js/application-45e23109c9e9d11521f0.hot-update.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "js": [
        "/packs/application-bdddc5e750615fa56298.js"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/application-bdddc5e750615fa56298.js.map",
        "/packs/js/application-45e23109c9e9d11521f0.hot-update.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my `config/webpacker.yml` file :

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: false

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: false

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

local:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
  check_yarn_integrity: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https:
      key: |
        -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
        ...
        -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
      cert: |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        ...
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      cacert: |
        -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
        ...
        -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 3035
    public: 0.0.0.0:3035
    hmr: true
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'

test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

*This app is using local as the development environment, so I renamed the development key to local*

BTW I have enabled `hmr`, but even with it disabled I have the same result.

Why are the files not written in the folder? And how could I fix this?

### Update

When I stop the `bin/webpack-dev-server` process and I reload the page, webpack recompile and the files are loading correctly in the webbrowser.

### Update 2

Opening the pack URL in a new tab show me the 500 error. I noticed that the pack URL is missing the 3035 port. Adding it returned me the expected JavaScript code.

So how to fix it so that the pack URL includes the server port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out what was wrong in my setup.

The first thing I understood is that with the `bin/webpack-dev-server` running, and as it catches the requests in order to serves them, the asset files aren't written in the `public/packs` folder anymore.
In the other hand, when stopping the server the files are written on the disk because they'll have to be served by Rails.

Then I realised that all was about my environment: I'm running my app using Docker and docker-compose + I'm using an Nginx reverse proxy (jwilder/nginx-proxy).

I was running the `bin/webpack-dev-server` using `docker-compose exec app bin/webpack-dev-server` in order to get it running aside with Rails.

To solve my issue:

1. I have declared a new container in my `docker-compose.yml` file, which has a `VIRTUAL_HOST` equal to `webpack.mydomain.co` and listening on port 3035.
2. I had then to update my SSL/TLS certificate in order to add this new sub domain and re-install the new certificates on my mac.
3. I have updated my `config/webpacker.yml` file to no more be in `https` (as nginx is taking care of that), and changing the `host` and `public` to `webpack.mydomain.co`
4. Finally I had to update the CSP rules to of course allow connect-src to `webpack.mydomain.co`.

With that done, the page loads without any issus, HMR works just fine as the `Hello World from Webpacker` message is refreshed in the Chrome console without reloading the current page.

I hope this could help people :)